# Authentication failed - Bad credentials in grails spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have created my users and roles in Bootstrap.groovy.

```
def user = new User(username:"name", password:"pass",email:"email@gmail.rr",enabled:true).save()
```

I have checked the usernames and passwords for each one directly in the database. 
I have even removed the encoding for testing purposes.
However, I get this when I try to login (there is some additional logging added by me)

> 2014-01-27 22:49:04,480 [http-bio-8090-exec-3] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   2014-01-27 22:49:04,480 [http-bio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   2014-01-27 23:06:19,654 [http-bio-8090-exec-7] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   2014-01-27 23:06:19,833 [http-bio-8090-exec-8] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   authentication
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc4a600: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: **grails.anonymous.user**; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 951C58071D49B3E3AB6D55C158C46B43; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   is NOT logged in
>   2014-01-27 23:06:29,147 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] DEBUG authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - Request is to process authentication
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,115 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] DEBUG authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,115 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] DEBUG authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,115 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] DEBUG authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - Delegating to authentication failure handler grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler@df9533
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,116 [http-bio-8090-exec-9] DEBUG authentication.AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler  - Redirecting to /login/authfail?login_error=1
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,165 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   authentication failed!!!!
>   2014-01-27 23:06:30,235 [http-bio-8090-exec-10] DEBUG filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: '{0}'
>   authentication
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc4a600: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: **grails.anonymous.user**; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 951C58071D49B3E3AB6D55C158C46B43; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
>   is NOT logged in

What do you understand from this stacktrace please? If any more information is needed, I would provide it with no hesitation :)

From what I see in the logs, when I try to login with the administrator user which I have created and verified in the database, spring security is trying to log in with the anonymous user who has no access to these pages
Here is some more spring security config

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/candidate/*': ['ROLE_ADMIN'],

 ]
```

Comment: This line: `Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false` Could it be possible you are trying to test with a disabled account?

Comment: Maybe, what should I do to verify?

Answer (score 1):

Not much to go on here :)  All it's saying is that the password is bad.

Since you didn't mention that this is an upgrade from 1.2.x of the plugin to 2.x it shouldn't be that there's a configuration issue. If it were that and you didn't make any config changes, you would have old passwords hashed with SHA-256 but would be comparing them with bcrypt-hashed passwords. Also, even if you configured it to use SHA-256, the number of number of hash iterations changed from 1 to 10000, so you'd need `grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1` in Config.groovy.

So I'm going to guess that you're explicitly hashing the password in BootStrap.groovy, e.g.

```
def user = new User(username: 'me', enabled: true, password: springSecurityService.encodePassword('super_secret')).save()
```

But the generated user class auto-hashes for you, so this hashes twice. If you're doing that, change the BootStrap code to

```
def user = new User(username: 'me', enabled: true, password: 'super_secret').save()
```

Comment: I have just edited the question and added the way I create my users in Bootstrap. I am not using the encoding/hashing because I had supposed that it can cause me troubles. I don't know if you can understand what is going wrong on with my code :)

Comment: Can you share the Config.groovy settings for password hashing, or are you using defaults?

Comment: I hesitate to copy paste the whole class because I don't think I have the right. I would like to ask you if you can tell me what exact setting you are talking about? Spring security settings?

Comment: Any settings in Config.groovy that start with "grails.plugin.springsecurity", e.g. `grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations`, that relate to password configuration

Comment: No, I don't have that setting. I guess it is the default

Comment: See this blog post, in particular the event listener code, and if that's not enough consider using a debugger: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003

Comment: I have added some more information that could be proven useful for finding a solution if possible. Thank you deeply for your previous answers anyway